# Vue Error in nextTick: "NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, html-framework-7

I am developing an application with the use of the vue and vue router and I had a problem when switching from one route to another, when I switch, it gives an error **Error in nextTick: "NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'** while json is loaded on both pages of routes and the list is rendered from v-for.

[I attached a message from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oVbH.png)

Comment: you should post the relevant pieces of code to get an answer to your question. cheers!

Comment: Also, the error message is truncated in the screenshot. There might be interesting detail in the part that's missing.

Comment: New printscreen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oVbH.png